# Silverlight and Imgur . Response: Not Found

Tags: c#, silverlight, imgur

Can you help me , i have problem with uploading image to imgur. I tried WebClient and HttpRequest and both returned me error Not Found.

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenWriteCompleted);
        Uri u = new Uri("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload");
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, null, new object[] { imageData, byteread }); // Upload the file to the server
    }

    void wc_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e) // The upload completed
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you handling authentication in your code? You have to register with imagur to perform uploads using the API.